# Load JSON file into table view causes so much CPU usage

Tags: swift3

I'm using the latest Xcode 8.2.1 and Swift 3.0.

I'm trying to get a JSON file from my PHP and display it into a table view, each JSON data for each table view row in a particular section. There're 4 sessions and I wish to group each of my data into each session. For example, the first session is customer details, I would like to group the customer name, address, contact into that group and each JSON occupies one row of the table view.

However, my MacBook Pro just get so hot and I checked "Activity Monitor", my CPU runs up to 345%. What am I doing wrong?

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    struct Objects {
        var sectionName : String!
        var sectionObject : [String]!
    }

    var objectsArray = [Objects]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        LoadJsonData()
    }

    func LoadJsonData () {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string:"http://<myphphttpaddressgoeshere>/appcpapi.php")! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let poststring = "tag=search&refno=17-0700"

        request.httpBody = poststring.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error= \(error)")
                return
            }
            else
            {
                do{
                    let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                        self.objectsArray = [MyTableViewController.Objects(sectionName: "Customer Details",sectionObject:["Ticket No \n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cp_tktno") ?? "No data")","Name \n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cpc_name") ?? "No data")","Customer IC \n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cpic_no") ?? "No data")","Address \n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cpaddress") ?? "No data")","District:\n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cpDistrict") ?? "No data")","Latitude GPS:\n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cplatitude") ?? "No data")","Longitude GPS:\n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cplongitude") ?? "No data")"]),MyTableViewController.Objects(sectionName: "Old Meter Details", sectionObject: ["Old Meter:\n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cpm_no") ?? "No data")","Old M. Tariff\n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cp_old_tariff") ?? "No data")","Old M. Brand \n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cptm_name") ?? "No data")","Old M. Type:\n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cpt_of_meter") ?? "No data")","Old M. Faulty:\n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cp_fault_type") ?? "No data")"]),MyTableViewController.Objects(sectionName: "New Meter Details", sectionObject:["a","b","c","d"]),MyTableViewController.Objects(sectionName: "Customer Signature", sectionObject: ["a,b,c,d"])]

                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    })
                }//Catch Error
                catch let error{
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return objectsArray[section].sectionObject.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as UITableViewCell!
        cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell?.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        cell?.textLabel?.text = objectsArray[indexPath.section].sectionObject[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        return objectsArray.count
    }//

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{
        return objectsArray[section].sectionName
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to provide the URL to the JSON data so that we can get an idea as to the size and complexity of the data?

Comment: @Fahim Thanks for your prompt response and help, my JSON look something like this:
{
    "ap_contact_no" = 2652195;
    "co_id" = 32;
    cpDistrict = "KUALA BELAIT";

    "cp_fault_type" = "OTHER;";
    "cp_old_tariff" = "";
    "cp_oldmeter_img" = "";
    "cp_replacemeter" = 37120628369;
    "cp_service_type" = "CHANGE METER;";
    "cp_tktno" = 0440262;
    "cp_voltage_l1" = "";
    "cp_voltage_l2" = "";
    "cp_voltage_l3" = "";
 
}

Comment: What I meant was, is there just that one item? Or do you actually have an array of those items? And if yes, how big is the array? Also, can you share the code for the `Object` class with us?

Comment: @Fahim Hi, yes, thats the only JSON data I get from php. Very small data and thats why I wonder why Xcode cause CPU runs up to 345%, maybe I'm doing something wrong in my code, like some looping cannot get out of the heap? Please advise.

Comment: I can't see any major issues with your code though you should probably do the array creation outside the main thread since the URL fetch response is handled in a background thread and the array processing can happen there. Just do the table reload on the main thread. If you can share the whole project, I can take a look to see what might be going on, but hard to do so by simply looking at snippets of code - at least, for me :)

Comment: Also, it is better to use Swift arrays and dictionaries with specific type information than `NSAarray` and `NSDictionary` ...

Comment: @Fahim Hi, I found a way to solve it,

let name = dictionary.value(forKey: "cpc_name") ?? "No data" 
                   
 OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
self.objectsArray =[MyTableViewController.Objects(sectionName: "Customer Details",sectionObject:["Name \n(name)"])] 
})

Thank you so much for your approach. Appreciate ^^

Comment: If it works for you, great :) But do consider switching over to Swift dictionaries and arrays since they are type safe :)

Comment: Not sure that I helped, but glad to have done something if it was helpful :)

Comment: @Fahim Oh ya, you mean switching to swift dictionaries instead of NSDictionary? Actually what is the difference between them? Sorry, I'm just new to Swift actually.

Comment: `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` are type agnostic - they do not know the type of objects they hold (unless you specify type using the newer syntax - which quite a few people don't). So you can add objects which are not the same type to a collection - this could lead to issues. Swift collections have to have the type defined explicitly. So they are safer since you can't add an `Int`, for example, to a `String` array by mistake.

Comment: @Fahim, Alright, I will try to do that, just create a var dictionaryname:[ type : type ] =[ : ], then I just put the output of JSON into dictionaryname?

Comment: I'll add the code as an answer - this comment thread is getting very long :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding switching to Swift dictionary instead of `NSDictionary`, the following code:

```
let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
    self.objectsArray = [MyTableViewController.Objects(sectionName: "Customer Details",sectionObject:["Ticket No \n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cp_tktno") ?? "No data")","Name \n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cpc_name") ?? "No data")","Customer IC \n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cpic_no") ?? "No data")","Address \n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cpaddress") ?? "No data")","District:\n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cpDistrict") ?? "No data")","Latitude GPS:\n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cplatitude") ?? "No data")","Longitude GPS:\n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cplongitude") ?? "No data")"]),MyTableViewController.Objects(sectionName: "Old Meter Details", sectionObject: ["Old Meter:\n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cpm_no") ?? "No data")","Old M. Tariff\n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cp_old_tariff") ?? "No data")","Old M. Brand \n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cptm_name") ?? "No data")","Old M. Type:\n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cpt_of_meter") ?? "No data")","Old M. Faulty:\n\(dictionary.value(forKey: "cp_fault_type") ?? "No data")"]),MyTableViewController.Objects(sectionName: "New Meter Details", sectionObject:["a","b","c","d"]),MyTableViewController.Objects(sectionName: "Customer Signature", sectionObject: ["a,b,c,d"])]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

Should look like this:

```
let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String:Any]
self.objectsArray = [MyTableViewController.Objects(sectionName: "Customer Details",sectionObject:["Ticket No \n\(dictionary["cp_tktno"] ?? "No data")","Name \n\(dictionary["cpc_name"] ?? "No data")","Customer IC \n\(dictionary["cpic_no"] ?? "No data")","Address \n\(dictionary["cpaddress"] ?? "No data")","District:\n\(dictionary["cpDistrict"] ?? "No data")","Latitude GPS:\n\(dictionary["cplatitude"] ?? "No data")","Longitude GPS:\n\(dictionary["cplongitude"] ?? "No data")"]),MyTableViewController.Objects(sectionName: "Old Meter Details", sectionObject: ["Old Meter:\n\(dictionary["cpm_no"] ?? "No data")","Old M. Tariff\n\(dictionary["cp_old_tariff"] ?? "No data")","Old M. Brand \n\(dictionary["cptm_name"] ?? "No data")","Old M. Type:\n\(dictionary["cpt_of_meter"] ?? "No data")","Old M. Faulty:\n\(dictionary["cp_fault_type"] ?? "No data")"]),MyTableViewController.Objects(sectionName: "New Meter Details", sectionObject:["a","b","c","d"]),MyTableViewController.Objects(sectionName: "Customer Signature", sectionObject: ["a,b,c,d"])]

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```